# How to implement Cronjob in Justhost?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

Every day I want to run a script and check for some conditions, and based on 
those conditions, I want to insert data into database.

I am using Cron-Job(Controller) to automate this process.
In the script file (i.e. Controller) which I am automating, I am trying to load ‘view’ file (script). Only the controller is getting executed, not the ‘view’ file , i.e data is not getting inserted to the database.

It’s the first time I am using Cron-Jobs, please guide me through.

```
* * * * * php /home/<cpanel_username>/public_html/index.php Controller_name
```

CodeIgniter framework (3.1) / PHP(5.6).

Hosting server: Justhost (cPanel 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below way of implement cronjob.

Example of job definition:

```
.---------------- minute (0 - 59) 
|
 .------------- hour (0 - 23) 
 | 
 | .---------- day of month (1 - 31) 
 | 
 | | .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ... 
 | 
 | | | .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat 
 | 
 | | | | 

* * * * * command to be executed
```

Comment: a comment linking to the manual would have sufficed.

Comment: @Kamlesh please share an example.

Comment: @Raham i have uploaded one example. In that i have set cron job for every 1 day. Could you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please find below example.

Which is i have used for every 1 day

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
0 0 * * 1 your/command
```